# React: Callback arrow functions vs direct trigger

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am not exactly sure how to describe it but let's say I have this code `<button onClick={() => exampleFunction}>Text</button>` and this code `<button onClick={exampleFunction}>Text</button>`, so what's the difference in both examples working? I noticed that in case of `onChange` only second example works.

Could anyone clarify it?

Comment: Do you actually mean `() => exampleFunction()` instead of `() => exampleFunction`?

Comment: in your first example you are declaring an anonymous arrow function , in your second example you are actually executing some function

Comment: yes, @rayhatfield explained it perfectly, but thank you

Answer (score 2):

In your first example you're not actually invoking `exampleFunction`. You're providing a function that *returns* `exampleFunction`.

This:

```
() => exampleFunction
```

is the equivalent of:

```js
function () { // invoked by the underlying component
  return exampleFunction; // returned, but never called.
}
```

To fix it, add the parens:

```js
() => exampleFunction()
```

In the second form, you're passing `exampleFunction` directly, which *is* a function. It gets invoked by the underlying component.